# How to display entire list as dropdown menu

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint Online. I have a site with 2 basic lists. I am now creating a sort of "portal" page for users of the site to get information from the lists. Instead of displaying the entire lists on the portal page, i want each list to be displayed as a dropdown menu. If a user selects an item in the dropdown list, then it should then display that item from that list.  This will be for displaying information only - no editing would be done via the portal.  Is there any way to do this either OOB or via SPD (i am not a developer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your requirement need to be done by coding so there is no way to get lists and insert them in dropdown and get listitems from specified list without code.